# Controller on Kaa Server

Tags: cassandra, raspberry-pi, sandbox, iot, kaa

I am using AWS for running Kaa-Sandbox instance & RaspberryPi as end point.

RaspberryPi is connected to multiple sensors. Sensors sending continuously data to RaspberryPi.

So I just wanted to analyse the data on Kaa Server like a controller, each time I will send data to this controller before pushing data directly into database I want to analyze the data.

For example: if sensed value of temperature is more then the allowed limit then it will send a command to RaspberryPi or some other controller to turn on or off heater or cooler according to their need.

Does it is possible to implement a controller like this on Kaa server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can implement it with Kaa.
Follow to [Kaa Data analytics and visualization best practices](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kaaproject/B56e8Hsf_5I)      and [Your best practices regarding "rules engine" in Kaa](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kaaproject/u5L8zEQvKNU) topics for details. 
Also, refer to our new [Key platform features](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/)  documentation instead of using outdated links mentioned in the topics.

Comment: I am newbie to kaa, So I need some more help from you, Can you explain a little deeper the rules via configuration and events with all necessary steps, It will be helpful for us who having the same problem like me.